# How to output values from one column to different columns in plsql?

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table in which several groups of values are entered in one column, each group of values corresponds to a certain "gg_number". You need to write a "select" like this to display values from the "val" column in multiple columns.
"gg_number" is a group of values that are on the same line and all values are in different columns.
"rw _id" is the column identifier.
For example, "gg_number = 0 ... n" and "rw _id = 100" will be one column. How to do it?

Code for adding values to the "val" column:

```
INSERT INTO tabl1.bg_s_stavka
  (
   id_stv,
   gg_number,
   rw_id,
   val,
   type_s,
   datebegin,
   dateend,
   type_fee,
   bg_period
  )
  SELECT tabl1.bg_fee_seq.nextval,
         row_ind('${hm.prow}'),
         col_ind(iNumber),
         to_number(replace(decode(iNumber,
                                  2,
                                  '${hm.pc2}',
                                  3,
                                  '${hm.pc3}',
                                  4,
                                  '${hm.pc4}',
                                  5,
                                  '${hm.pc5}',
                                  6,
                                  '${hm.pc6}',
                                  7,
                                  '${hm.pc7}',
                                  8,
                                  '${hm.pc8}',
                                  9,
                                  '${hm.pc9}',
                                  10,
                                  '${hm.pc10}',
                                  11,
                                  '${hm.pc11}',
                                  12,
                                  '${hm.pc12}',
                                  13,
                                  '${hm.pc13}',
                                  14,
                                  '${hm.pc14}',
                                  15,
                                  '${hm.pc15}',
                                  16,
                                  '${hm.pc16}',
                                  17,
                                  '${hm.pc17}',
                                  18,
                                  '${hm.pc18}',
                                  19,
                                  '${hm.pc19}',
                                  0),
                           '.',
                           Oracle_Decimal)),
         2,
         to_date('${PMM}' || '.' || '${PYYYY}', 'mm.yyyy'),
         last_day(to_date('${PMM}' || '.' || '${PYYYY}', 'mm.yyyy')),
         102,
         0
    FROM dual;


GG_NUMBER  RW_ID   VAL  
    0       100   939,7     
    0        1    787,4
    1       100   128,7 
    1        1    124,1
```

You need to write a SELECT Statement to get the output:

```
    t1          t2     
   939,7       787,4   
   128,7       124,1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when rw_id = 100 then val end) as t1,
       max(case when rw_id = 1 then val end) as t2       
from tabl1.bg_s_stavka
group by gc_number
```

Comment: Thank! May I ask you any contact you have, just in case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get values of `val` columns for extremum values of `rw_id` columns when grouped by `gg_number`.

To accomplish this, `MAX(rw_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST/FIRST ORDER BY ...) ) OVER (PARTITION BY ..` analytic function might be used

(
`...DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY rw_id...` yields **max** value of `rw_id`,

`...DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY rw_id...` yields **min** value of `rw_id` ) :

```
WITH bgs AS
(     
SELECT gg_number,
       CASE WHEN MAX(rw_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY rw_id) OVER 
           (PARTITION BY gg_number) = rw_id THEN val END AS t1,
       CASE WHEN MAX(rw_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY rw_id) OVER 
           (PARTITION BY gg_number) = rw_id THEN val END AS t2 
  FROM bg_s_stavka 
)
SELECT MAX(t1) AS t1, MAX(t2) AS t2
  FROM bgs
 GROUP BY gg_number 
 ORDER BY gg_number;

T1      T2
-----   -----
939,7   787,4
128,7   124,1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d5aba65a5d820d2be853835a5ff49e96)</kbd>